# How to calculate cumulative standards errors from several ones?

Tags: r, standard-error, effect-size

I want to estimate the cumulative effects of air pollution on mortality using GLM or Gam methods. With the following R code I was able to estimate the cumulative effect of PM10 on mortality which is estimated as 0.001513801 (1.51% increase in mortality for a 10 ug/m3 increase in PM10 ).  My question is how can I build get the total standard error for estimates from lag 0 to 4 and build 95 % confidence interval for the cumulative estimate? Is it statistically valid to add up the standard errors just like the beta estimates from the output?

I would also like to know if there are alternative methods of obtaining the total estimates with standard errors.

```
library(dlnm) 
library(quantmod)
chic <- chicagoNMMAPS
fit <- glm(death ~ Lag(pm10, 0:4) + temp, data = chic,   family = poisson)
summ <- summary(fit)

Call:
glm(formula = death ~ Lag(pm10, 0:4) + temp, family = poisson, 
    data = chic)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-4.0461  -0.8594  -0.0705   0.7390  22.4579  

Coefficients:
                      Estimate Std. Error  z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)          4.749e+00  4.414e-03 1075.916  < 2e-16 ***
Lag(pm10, 0:4)Lag.0  8.395e-04  8.362e-05   10.040  < 2e-16 ***
Lag(pm10, 0:4)Lag.1  4.980e-04  8.993e-05    5.537 3.07e-08 ***
Lag(pm10, 0:4)Lag.2 -2.279e-05  9.007e-05   -0.253   0.8003    
Lag(pm10, 0:4)Lag.3  2.198e-04  8.953e-05    2.455   0.0141 *  
Lag(pm10, 0:4)Lag.4 -2.068e-05  8.312e-05   -0.249   0.8035    
temp                -5.608e-03  1.520e-04  -36.902  < 2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for poisson family taken to be 1)
```

To obtain the total (cumulative ) effects for lags 0 to 4):

```
rown <- rownames(summ$coefficients)
        tot <- grep("pm10", rown, fixed = TRUE)
        coefs <- summ$coefficients[tot , "Estimate"]
total <- sum(coefs)
total 
[1] 0.001513801
```

So in short how do I get total standard errors for lag 0:4?

Comment: "*0.001513801 (1.35% increase in mortality)*" -- how do you get 1.35% ?

Comment: It was a mistake, see my edit. Thanks for noting it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the random vector $X$ has a covariance matrix $\Sigma$, then the variance of the linear combination $a'X$ is $a'\Sigma a$. In your case $a$ consists of ones. So you need to get the covariance matrix of the coefficient do some matrix multiplication.

The covariance matrix of the `glm` coefficients is provided by function `vcov`. So in your case the following code should provide the standard error:

```
a <- c(0,rep(1,5),0)
sqrt(sum(crossprod(a,vcov(fit))*a))
[1] 0.0001394239
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that you need library(quantmod) for the lag function